# Connect to a Windows Server 2012 share from OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, networking, vpn, network-shares, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having problems connecting to a Windows Server 2012 share from my iMac.
I'm connected to the server via VPN, which seems to be working:
[image: The VPN connection itself]

Now when I try to connect to the share by typing smb://username:share@192.168.1.105/share into the Connect to Server dialog, OS X craps out on me:
[image]

On my old PC this wasn't a problem, I simply connected to the VPN, added my server shares as network drives and that was it. Can anyone please tell me how to do it on OS X?

Comment: Isn't 192.168.1.105 your IP address, not the server's?

Comment: Nope, it's the server's address. Due to the VPN, it's got a 'local' IP address.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that IP is yours and not the server's... I did a test on my Mac... If you run ifconfig in terminal you'll see that IP is assigned to your Mac, for the VPN connection.

Comment: In that case, what *is* the server's IP? I'm fairly new to OS X, and need help with this.

Comment: In some cases the server should appear in Finder (at least in my experience with local networks, not VPNs). Now, if the server is also connected to the VPN, it should have an IP in the same class as you (192.168.1.x). If the server is in a network, and the VPN is just a way of connecting to that network your server IP could be different all together. You should know the IP of your server. If you don't then I guess you'll have to search for it using a network searching tool, but you have to do some research yourself on that, as I' not familiar with any...

Comment: Well, I checked the server itself and tried connecting using an IP I found there. Now it's working, for whatever reason. For anyone with a similar problem, try opening the Computer Management window on your server and going to Services and Applications -> Routing and Remote Access -> IPv4 -> General and trying the IP next to "Internal" there.

Comment: Actually, you can just run `ipconfig`, and get the right IP from the list. :)

Comment: Its output looked like gibberish to me, sorry :D I'm sure you can do amazing stuff using only Terminal, but that's not my world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same problem, go here on your server:
[image]
and try connecting using the internal IP.

This was probably something really obvious, but I'm not familiar with networking stuff and I hope this helps people who aren't as well.